# git clone vs git pull

Tags: git, github, repository, git-pull, git-clone

For my project I keep an online repository on `github` and local repositories on two computers (say A, B) where I write code and run tests and also on three other machines (say, C, D, E) where I just run tests.

Now, it happened a few times that there are conflicts whenever I want to just download updated code on C, D, E and doing just `git pull origin $someBranch` won't work, probably due to some small modifications that I did on the local source code just for testing purposes and which I don't want to keep.

What should I do in this case? Should I always do `git clone $URLofMyRepository` or are there less aggressive ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the changes to your branch **if you do not want to keep them** using:

```
git checkout .
```

This should remove all unsaved changes to your working directory, allowing you to perform a pull.

```
git pull origin $someBranch
```

If you want to keep the changes in your branch try stashing them, then running the pull command.

```
git stash
```

Assuming no other stashes have occurred these changes can be applied at a later time by performing:

```
git stash apply
```

Comment: @RickyRobinson I updated my answer.  Basically its going to remove all changes that you have made to the branch, by reverting the files back to the last commit.

Comment: OK. I messed up a bit with my files and there was an "file unmerged" message which prevented `pull` from completing. So in the end I had to remove everything and `clone` from the repository.